# Putting a meshed object on perspective grid

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, grids, perspective, gradient-mesh

I am working on a picture of a room. The room has a poster in it. I created a symbol of the poster, and it includes a picture of a soccer ball, shaded with gradient mesh. Unfortunately, I cannot put this poster on the perspective grid because of the mesh. Is there a way to convert the meshed objects (while preserving the look of the image) to a regular vector graphic that can be placed on the perspective grid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put gradient meshes or raster images on a perspective grid. So first you have to rasterize the gradient mesh (Object > Rasterize), and then you have use an envelop distort to get the rasterized image in perspective. Here's how you do that:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8M8P6lhRnwg&app=desktop

Comment: Thank you. It's been a few years since I posted this, but I'll keep it in mind if I ever need to do something like this again. Meantime, I have another question I need answered. Could you please take a look at it? :) https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/137583/trying-to-put-a-guide-layer-within-a-mask

Comment: @julie1013 since you're here, might as well mark one of these answers as accepted (put the green tick mark besides the answer that suits your question the best) to help keep the site organized.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately perspective is not a linear operation. What that means is that the interpolation of mesh can not happen in perspective so it wouldn't be able to hold the same look.

The only way to really do this is to rasterize the mesh objects to a pixel image.

Answer (score 0):

Export the mesh to jpeg. Then place the same jpeg. Then trace the jpeg to a high fidelity photo and expand. Now the image is ready to be placed on the perspective grid