# Trying to put a guide layer within a mask

Tags: mask, guides, adobe-animate

I'm doing an animation with a planet revolving around an object. I used a guide layer to create the animation so that the planet goes along the ellipse. In order for the planet to go behind the object, I of course need a mask. But it seems that I can only use either a guide layer or mask layer for an object, not both. I tried Googling the issue; it's coming up dry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I didn't think of this before. I put the animation of the planet and the guide in its own symbol. Then, I applied the mask to the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the mask, you could duplicate the object the planet is orbiting around on a different layer. Put one layer above and one layer below the planet in the stacking order and then use opacity to switch between them.